# Oracle Solaris 11.2 hangs during installation

Tags: boot, system-installation, solaris, opensolaris

I'm in the process of installing OracleSolaris 11.2 (taken from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris11/downloads/install-2245079.html) on PC with the following spec:

```
Intel Core2 Quad CPU 2.5Ghz
RAM 8Gb
Motherboard is ASUS P5Q-EM (https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P5QEM/)
```

It starts booting:

```
  Booting 'Oracle Solaris 11.2'

Loading cd/platform/i86pc/kernel/amd64/unix: done
Loading cd/platform/i86pc/amd64/boot_archive: done

SunOS Release 5.11 Version 11.2 64-bit
Copyright (c) 1983, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
```

At this point it hangs, looks like it freezes completely as even the keyboard doesn't react. What is way to go in such situations, is there a way to get a hint on what exactly goes wrong?

**UPDATE**
After I have added 'verbose' flag to kernel boot command, I see that the boot process hangs up at the following:

```
...
PCI Express-device: pci1043,82d4@1d,7, ehci1
ehci1 is /pci@0,0/pci1043,82d4@1d,7
```

It appears that usb controller on my motherboard is faulty or not correctly supported by Solaris 11.2 (it does have no problems under Linux though). I disabled it in the BIOS, as I don't need it.

Comment: Try to boot in verbose mode to see where it freezes, see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E28983/glyas.html on how to add the `-v` verbose option

Comment: In addition to what @Lambert added, probably you might have to disable certain features. Check the Hardware compatibility list for further info. http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/hcl/data/s11ga/index.html

Comment: @BitsOfNix, does the Oracle's Hardware compatibility list only enlists hardware that was reported to boot solaris etc., it doesn't mean that anything else would not be supported by solaris?

Comment: @Lambert, when installing OracleSolaris with text installer, I do not see the grub menu and thus can't modify kernel boot parameters. Is it expected?

Comment: If you boot from the cdrom you will briefly see a grub message with a countdown timer of 5 seconds. Press the escape key within the countdown period to get the grub menu. You can then choose of four options, boot Solaris 11.2, with ttya, with ttyb and boot from harddisk